# "Perforated" polygon voids are filled when using OpenLayers with WKB geometries

Tags: openlayers, well-known-text, well-known-binary, drawing

When I try to draw a "perforated" polygon using [GeoJSON.readFeatures()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_JSONFeature-JSONFeature.html#readFeatures) the "solid/void" relationship is drawn correctly, the void parts don't have any fill color. See the example, GeoJSON included: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-beaver-0fzuf

And here is the result, which is the desired one:

[image]

But when I use the [WKB Geometry](https://0bin.net/paste/KMefJajA#PEzMwiVTXltU5b840deAHPYbKbeYslw2glW8noI18NS) that's coming from PostGIS and creating the feature with:

```
polygonWkbGeometryFromPostGis.coordinates.forEach((coords) => {
        const feature = new Feature({
          geometry: new Polygon([coords]);
        });
      });
```

I get all the voids filled with color, which is wrong:

[image: wrong]

Just in case, the WKB geometry ([link to this example's text representation](https://0bin.net/paste/KMefJajA#PEzMwiVTXltU5b840deAHPYbKbeYslw2glW8noI18NS)) is being displayed correctly in the DB client as well:

[image]

In both examples I'm using OpenLayers 6.5.0 and the exact same *ol/style*.

What's causing the issue?

Comment: You are creating multiple overlapping Polygon features from the coordinates of each ring.  For a single polygon with holes use `new Polygon(polygonWkbGeometryFromPostGis.coordinates)`

Comment: Or you could readFeatures from the WKT string in the same way as you readFeatures from the GeoJSON https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-williams-wv3gh

Comment: @Mike Can you post these as an answer so that I can accept? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple overlapping Polygon features from the coordinates of each ring. For a single polygon with holes use

```
new Feature({
  geometry: new Polygon(polygonWkbGeometryFromPostGis.coordinates)
})
```

Or you could `readFeatures` from the WKT string in the same way as you `readFeatures` from the GeoJSON https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-williams-wv3gh